# When to use Method of Images for electrostatic field problems?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, method-of-images

I have been solving some questions regarding electrostatic fields, and I'm not quite sure when and when not to apply the method of images.

As I understand it, 'method of images' is simply replacing bounding surfaces with appropriate image charges so that it also satisfies the boundary conditions given. Because of the uniqueness of electrostatic solutions, the solution for the original problem with the bounding surfaces has to be identical with the one regarding only the image charges.

I also know that we can use this technique for certain problems such as the point charge and conducting plane problem, the line charge and parallel conducting cylinder problem, etc.

But consider the problem below.

> Q. A charged half-cylindrical sheet (r = b/2, 0 < φ < π) of uniform surface charge density ρs = ρ0, inside the cylindrical conducting shell (r = b) with electric potential V = 0.
> Find the potential at any point.

According to method of images, can't we just replace the cylindrical conducting shell with image line charges inside the cylinder so that the problem above becomes the same as deducing potential at any point outside of a charged cylindrical sheet (r = b/2, 0 < φ < 2π) of density ps = p0/2?
(Intuitively I know this is wrong, but I can't understand why)

In theory, those two problems have the same boundary conditions (electric potential V = 0 at r = b), so shouldn't the solution also be unique? Or am I missing something obvious..?